# Colors with git-bash on windows

Tags: windows, shell, mingw32, git-bash

I didn't know where to post it.
I just have installed git-bash and arcanist project (http://www.phabricator.com/docs/phabricator/article/Arcanist_User_Guide.html).

Now when I type "arc help" on command prompt I get the following message :

```
bcohen@BCOHEN-L ~
$ arc help
←[1mNAME←[m
      ←[1marc←[m - arcanist, a code review and revision management utility

←[1mSYNOPSIS←[m
      ←[1marc←[m ←[4mcommand←[m [←[4moptions←[m] [←[4margs←[m]
      This help file provides a detailed command reference.

←[1mCOMMAND REFERENCE←[m

      ←[1malias←[m
      ←[1malias←[m ←[4mcommand←[m
      ←[1malias←[m ←[4mcommand←[m ←[4mtarget←[m -- [←[4moptions←[m]

      ←[1mamend←[m [--revision ←[4mrevision_id←[m] [--show]

      ←[1manoid←[m

      ←[1mbackout←[m

      ←[1mbookmark←[m [←[4moptions←[m]
      ←[1mbookmark←[m ←[4mname←[m [←[4mstart←[m]

      ←[1mbranch←[m [←[4moptions←[m]
      ←[1mbranch←[m ←[4mname←[m [←[4mstart←[m]

      ←[1mbrowse←[m [←[4moptions←[m] ←[4mpath←[m ...

      ←[1mcall-conduit←[m ←[4mmethod←[m

      ←[1mclose←[m ←[4mtask_id←[m [←[4moptions←[m]

      ←[1mclose-revision←[m [←[4moptions←[m] ←[4mrevision←[m

      ←[1mcommit←[m [--revision ←[4mrevision_id←[m] [--show]

      ←[1mcover←[m [--rev ←[4mrevision←[m] [←[4mpath←[m ...]

      ←[1mdiff←[m [←[4mpaths←[m] (svn)
      ←[1mdiff←[m [←[4mcommit←[m] (git, hg)
```

For having colors, I must replace with sed the ← by \033 as following :

```
bcohen@BCOHEN-L ~
$ arc help |sed "s/?/\033/m"
NAME
      arc - arcanist, a code review and revision management utility

SYNOPSIS
      arc command [options] [args]
      This help file provides a detailed command reference.

COMMAND REFERENCE

      alias
      alias command
      alias command target -- [options]

      amend [--revision revision_id] [--show]

      anoid

      backout

      bookmark [options]
      bookmark name [start]

      branch [options]
      branch name [start]

      browse [options] path ...

      call-conduit method

      close task_id [options]

      close-revision [options] revision

      commit [--revision revision_id] [--show]
```

Do you have an idea ?
Maybe with an alias ?
Maybe by changing the encoding ?

Just a clue :

```
bcohen@BCOHEN-L ~
$ echo -e "\033[,4mtoto"
toto
```

This wode work whereas :

```
bcohen@BCOHEN-L ~
$ php -r 'echo "\033[1mtoto", PHP_EOL;'
←[1mtoto
```

doesn't work :(

Comment: In your current Term Window (xterm, putty, or ??). try `savTERM="$TERM": export TERM=xterm-color` ; That might solve it. If not, then restore your TERM from savTERM like `export TERM="$savTERM"; `. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you shelter, I'm using git-bash (mingw32) and tried your export but it didn't work

Comment: best to add `mingw32` as a tag to your question. That is a unique environment. I don't see much else I can comment on. If you don't get any nibbles here, check for a specific help site for `arcanist`. Good luck.

Comment: A year later and I'm having the exact same issue... find anything?